# return paypal data to localhost

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I would like to know to return data from paypal to localhost that is not accessible on the internet. Paypal IPN does not support localhost. Is there any alternative other than Paypal IPN?

Note: do not intend to do portforwarding or host in any public website

Comment: What programming language? What have you tried so far? Could you post some code as an example?

Answer (score 0):

Try https://requestb.in/ !  This allows us to collect inspect web requests.